# C++: Call a non static method from macro

Tags: c++, macros, typedef, variadic-functions, method-call

I was testing some features of c++ with varargs when I eventually got blocked by a macro call.

First, I have a class :

```
class TestManager
{
public:
    void            assertTestSeq(int n, ...);
    [...]
```

And I want to be able to call this method, without having to bother about **n** (number of varargs).
So, I copied from internet, that macro which counts the number of arguments:

```
#define NUMARGS(...)            NUMARGS_IMPL_((__VA_ARGS__, 63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
#define NUMARGS_IMPL_(tuple)    NUMARGS_IMPL tuple
#define NUMARGS_IMPL(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,N,...) N
```

Finally, I decided to create a macro to handle the counting:

```
#define assertSeq(...)      (TestManager::*assertTestSeq(NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__))
```

And tried to call it:

```
this->assertSeq(randomSheit1, randSht2);
```

BUT ... well, I don't know **how to declare** my assertSeq macro and then, I don't know **how to call** it either. Can you tell me if this could be done somehow and how?

Comment: Macros do simple text processing (in one pass). Just think about how your statements will turn out to be seen by the c++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with variadic templates:

```
template<typename Args...> void assertSeq(Args&&... args) {
  asserTestSeq(sizeof...(args), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The complicated-looking `&&` and `std::forward` stuff is to enable [perfect forwarding](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/). Other than that, `sizeof...` gives the size of an argument pack, and the second parameter is unpacking said pack in the same manner in which it was given to `assertSeq`.

Comment: I already tried it, without success, but I think it's because I'm using VS2012... I have to switch to VS2013 to test this c++11 feature.

Comment: I think to use this with VS2012, you need the [November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515).

Comment: I saw your last comment a bit late. However I managed to install VS2013 and this is working WELL. Very happy about it, a bit less happy about the syntax of variadic templates. But at least, one can now get rid of a few old sneaky macros.